# Catching webmethod parameter error

Tags: exception, webmethod

I have a webmethod like that

```
    
    [WebMethod]
    public static string UpdateProduct(Products obj)
    {
        DbTools.runcmd(TSQLCreate.Update(obj));
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

and have a XHR request that created with JS for passing obj to wetmethod

```
    
    SendOBJToMethod("some.aspx/UpdateProduct"
    ,obj // My Product Object
    ,function() { alert("Updated"); }); //SUCCESS FUNC
```

and Product class is like that

```
    
    public class Products : Books
    {
        public Products()
        {
            this.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
            ///throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region COMMON
        [SQLIDColumn]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [SQLColumn]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [SQLColumn]
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        [SQLColumn]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        ..............
        private bool isOnePrice;
        [SQLColumn]
        public bool IsOnePrice
        {
            get { return isOnePrice; }
            set { isOnePrice = value; }
        }

        private decimal onePrice;
        [SQLColumn]
        public decimal OnePrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (onePrice == 0M) onePrice = labelPrice;
                return onePrice;
            }
            set {onePrice = value;}
        }
    }
```

Problem:
When I send the object(product) as property(decimal) OnePrice is empty, I getting an error "is not valid value for decimal".

Let me know this, exception thrown by whom?
Because I want to change this message.

Thanks.